# How to fix component generation error in gnuradio-redhawk integration?

Tags: python, redhawksdr

I tried to deploy a GNURadio Flow Graph as a Component with GNURadio-REDHAWK Integration (https://github.com/GeonTech/gnuradio-redhawk). I selected Traditional Integration way (https://github.com/Geontech/gnuradio-redhawk/tree/master/1-traditional) and used *gr-redhawk_integration_python* and *gr-component_converter packages*.

An error occurred during the Component Generation with *redhawk-codegen* execute

My system and tools versions: CentOS Linux 7, Python 2.7.5, REDHAWK 2.2.1, GNU Radio 3.7.9. Details:

```
[pol-coolov@centoshost ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

[pol-coolov@centoshost ~]$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.5
[pol-coolov@centoshost ~]$ 

gov.redhawk.core (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Core"
gov.redhawk.core.sdk (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Core"
gov.redhawk.core.source (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Core"
gov.redhawk.core.ui (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Common UI"
gov.redhawk.core.ui.source (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Common UI"
gov.redhawk.e4.platform (2.2.1.201811291837) "REDHAWK e4 Platform"
gov.redhawk.ide.codegen (2.2.1.201811291834) "REDHAWK Jinja Code Generator Base"
gov.redhawk.ide.codegen.source (2.2.1.201811291834) "REDHAWK Jinja Code Generator Base"
gov.redhawk.ide.feature (2.2.1.201811291831) "REDHAWK IDE"
gov.redhawk.ide.feature.source (2.2.1.201811291831) "REDHAWK IDE"
gov.redhawk.ide.ui.feature (2.2.1.201811291831) "REDHAWK IDE UI"
gov.redhawk.ide.ui.feature.source (2.2.1.201811291831) "REDHAWK IDE UI"
gov.redhawk.idl (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK IDL Support"
gov.redhawk.idl.source (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK IDL Support"
gov.redhawk.validation.feature (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Validation"
gov.redhawk.validation.feature.source (2.2.1.201811291823) "REDHAWK Validation"
mil.jpeojtrs.sca (2.2.2.201811291820) "REDHAWK XML Model Utils"
mil.jpeojtrs.sca.source (2.2.2.201811291820) "REDHAWK XML Model Utils"


[pol-coolov@centoshost ~]$ gnuradio-config-info -v
3.7.9
```

After installing the GNU Radio has installed packages: *gr-redhawk_integration_python*, *gr-component_converter*. Created and configured the Flow Graph to meet requirements with *redhawk_source* and *redhawk_sink* blocks.

An error occurred during the Component Generation:

```
[pol-coolov@centoshost converter]$  ./run.py /home/pol-coolov/gnuradio_apps/my_gr_apps/gnur_redhawk/gnur_red_spectrum_inversion_flow.grc /home/pol-coolov/gnuradio_redhawk/gnuradio_components/spectrum_inversion_flow
>>> Warning: This flow graph may not have flow control: no audio or RF hardware blocks found. Add a Misc->Throttle block to your flow graph to avoid CPU congestion.
Skipped substitution for: class top_block\(.*\):
gnur_red_spectrum_inversion_flow
Component gnur_red_spectrum_inversion_flow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/bin/redhawk-codegen", line 416, in <module>
    generated, skipped = generator.generate(softpkg, *implFiles)
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/jinja/generator.py", line 161, in generate
    component = self.map(softpkg)
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/jinja/generator.py", line 301, in map
    return self.projectMapper().mapProject(softpkg, self.generators)
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/jinja/mapping.py", line 285, in mapProject
    project = self.mapComponent(softpkg)
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/jinja/mapping.py", line 198, in mapComponent
    component.update(self._mapComponent(softpkg))
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/jinja/project/component/mapping.py", line 38, in _mapComponent
    component['interfaces'] = [libraries.getRPMDependency(name) for name in self.getInterfaceNamespaces(softpkg)]
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/jinja/mapping.py", line 236, in getInterfaceNamespaces
    namespace = IDLInterface(interface.repid).namespace()
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/redhawk/codegen/lang/idl.py", line 36, in __init__
    interface = self.__repid.split(':')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
[pol-coolov@centoshost converter]$
```

Maybe the reason for the error in the difference of REDHAWK versions (need 2.0.6, but my version is 2.2.1)?
May I ask how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The submodules referenced in https://github.com/GeonTech/gnuradio-redhawk were developed against an older version of REDHAWK.